# Simple checkbox drawing program does not load

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm creating a checkbox drawing program using HTML and JavaScript. It basically (at this early stage) involves drawing an 100 x 100 square of checkboxes. The problem is, every time I try to load the page, it doesn't load. It simply displays the spinning half circle (I'm using chrome) forever. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function drawBoxes()
{
    for(var i = 0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0;j<100;j++)
        {
            document.getElementById('drawarea').innerHTML += "<input type = 'checkbox'>";
        }
        document.getElementById('drawarea').innerHTML += "<br />";
    }
}

</script>
<title>Checkbox drawer</title>
</head>
<body onload = "drawBoxes()">
<div id = "controlbar" style = "height:100px;float:top;background-color:#FF0000;"><p>hello</p></div>
<p id ="drawarea"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: After adding jcubic's catch of the `<input>` tag, the first `<div>` (in red) loads, but the checkboxes don't.

Comment: html don't have `checkbox` tag only `<input type="checkbox"/>`

Comment: @jcubic um still doesn't work. thanks for the catch tho, will edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the DOM 100*100 times, just build a string and set the value once at the end of the loops:

```
var html = "";

for(var i = 0;i<100;i++)
{
   for(var j = 0;j<5;j++)
   {
       html += "<input type = 'checkbox'>";
   }
   html += "<br />";
}

document.getElementById('drawarea').innerHTML = html;
```

Here's the JSFiddle to see that this load very quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/8hVBQ/

Comment: Thanks very much :) I should have known manipulating the dom so much was not a great plan